# Thymeleaf - Click able URL (Web link) in Table

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

(I have looked on google, here.. and havent been able to find the answer that could help me).

Goal : Website to be entered as a click able web link
- Link is retrieved from DB as a varchar(100)

Tried all kinds of different solutions.. without any luck - Maybe one of you guys can help me out ? :). thank you in advance.

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">

    <thead>

    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Zip</th>
        <th>Website</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Agelimit</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="sps: ${sp}">
        <td th:text="${sps.venueId}"/>
        <td th:text="${sps.name}"/>
        <td th:text="${sps.address}"/>
        <td th:text="${sps.city}"/>
        <td th:text="${sps.zip}"/>
        <td th:text="${sps.website}"/>
        <td th:text="${sps.email}"/>
        <td th:text="${sps.phone}"/>
        <td th:text="${sps.location}"/>
        <td th:text="${sps.ageLimit}"/>


    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use any type of tag with Thymeleaf.  Is this what you want?

```
<td>
    <a th:href="${sps.website}" th:text="${sps.website}" target="_blank" />
</td>
```

Comment: Metroids - Thank you! It almost work now, it is click able now, but it does link for: http://localhost:8080/detailsvenue_admin/www.rust.dk and not just http://www.rust.dk as it should ?.

Comment: Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Dec 05 16:42:35 CET 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "www.rust.dk"

Comment: You should store the complete url in the database... you should have `http://rust.dk`, or `https://rust.dk`.

Comment: What if I want to change the actual URL with a LINK in the table (sometimes URL are very long) - and when you hit LINK it execuses the actual URL ?.

Comment: <td>
         <a th:href="${sps.location}" target="_blank">Google Maps</a></td>               - "Google Maps" is now the Clickable link.